# unix command move file without accessing other folders in same directory

Tags: linux, command-line

I would like to move file from one folder to backup folder but without accessing others folder in the same directory. The Current Command that I used :-

```
find /interface/y0xi/gis/data -type f \( -name "*" \) -newerat "2014-01-01 00:00" -not -newerat "2019-03-31 23:59" -exec mv {} /interface/y0xi/gis/data/backup_fy21/ \;
```

but it accessing other folder under "data" Directory which is time consuming as there is a lot files and it been running for past three days non-stop.

I would really appreciate on your advise on this part.

Comment: Have you tried `-maxdepth 0`?

Comment: hi , You meant to say

find /interface/y0xi/gis/data -maxdepth 0 -type f \( -name "*" \) -newerat "2014-01-01 00:00" -not -newerat "2019-03-31 23:59" -exec mv {} /interface/y0xi/gis/data/backup_fy21/ \;

Comment: Thank you, it working but i have change to "-maxdepth 1 " and add "mv -t "